# Simulate character melting but retaining some volume

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I'm trying to recreate this gif of vaporeon melting ( https://c.tenor.com/TAB--fTTrwQAAAAC/pokemon-vaporeon.gif ) with a model of my own character. However, when using soft body physics, the mesh crumples too much and doesn't maintain a more soft rounded shape.

[image]

the closest i've gotten is after adding extra geometry "struts" inside of their body, but even then it looks a little too crumpled

[image]

for reference, here's the original model, and the settings i used for the soft body physics.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try increasing the bending. Of course it depends on other values as well and on your model.

I tried with this model:

[image]

and with self collision checked and a bending of 10 i got this:

[image]

and this is the result of just using the default cloth modifier with checked pressure:

[image]

and this with pressure of 5 (you could even animate the pressure and lower it over time)

[image]